# How do I disable "TODO" warnings in pylint?

Tags: pylint

When running pylint on a python file it shows me warnings regarding TODO comments by default. E.g.:

> ************* Module foo
>   W:200, 0: TODO(SE): fix this! (fixme)
>   W:294, 0: TODO(SE): backlog item (fixme)
>   W:412, 0: TODO(SE): Delete bucket? (fixme)

While I do find this behavior useful, I would like to know of a way of temporarily and/or permanently turn these specific warnings on or off.

I am able to generate a pylint config file:
`pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc`

I'm just note sure what to put in this file to disable warnings for TODO comments.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

in the generated config file, you should see a section

```
  [MISCELLANEOUS]

  # List of note tags to take in consideration, separated by a comma.
  notes=FIXME,XXX,TODO
```

simply drop TODO from the "notes" list.

The config file is found at

```
~/.pylintrc
```

If you have not generated the config file, this can be done with

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

Comment: Todo seems like a cool feature with pylint. Is it possible to have a "todo" block instead of a single line? Thanks.

Comment: This feels like a very wrong way to disable it temporarily as you can't check if new TODOs were added or removed. captainblack's answer looks more correct

Comment: Is there a way to do the same using the VS Code settings for pylint rather than a .pylintrc file ?

Comment: @vianmixt If you are using VS Code, pass this argument then: `--disable=fixme`.

Answer (score 14):

Along with the solution posted by @sthenault where you could disable all warnings, Pylint also allows you to ignore a single line (helpful if you would want to deal with it in the future) like so:

```
A_CONSTANT = 'ugh.'  # TODO: update value  # pylint: disable=fixme
```

or by stating the Rule ID:

```
A_CONSTANT = 'ugh.'  # TODO: update value  # pylint: disable=W0511
```

Comment: Note that if your `# TODO` comment starts at the start of a line (i.e. it's a block comment rather than an inline comment, even if only a single line), adding `# pyline: disable=fixme` to the same line will disable the fixme rule for the whole scope (e.g. function). I don't think there a way to tell pylint to ignore a single TODO comment in a block comment.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO your code should not have `# TODO` but during development it might be needed to have `TODO` for a short period of time and in this case pylint will bother you. To avoid this during this time the best is to globally disable it in the pylintrc by adding `fixme` to the `disable` list like this:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
# globally disable pylint checks (comma separated)
disable=fixme,...
```

So it let you the time to fix all your TODO and once this is done, you can remove the `fixme` from the pylintrc. Note if you use an older pylint version you will need to use `W0511` instead of `fixme`. For more detail see https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/technical_reference/features.html#messages-control-options

Changing the pylintrc `notes` as proposed in the first answer is a bad practice in my opinion. `notes` is designed to configure wich comments triggers the `fixme` warning and not designed to disable the warning.

Answer (score 0):

In our projects we have a **pylint.cfg** file. We use the `--rcfile` pylint option to point to that file.

In pylint.cfg, I can disable checker **W0511**, which is the checker that complains about "TODO" and similar terms in comments. Just add `W0511` to the comma-separated list for parameter `disable`.

*But remember that, as Uncle Bob Martin says, a TODO is not an excuse to leave bad code in the system, and the code should be scanned regularly to remove TODOs, and pylint and/or sonarqube issues can work as good reminders and motivation for doing so.*