# What is this PyLint warning on my TODO comment, and how can I ignore it?

Tags: python, warnings, lint, pylint

PyLint in VS Code is giving me this warning when I add a `# TODO` comment.

[image]

I can't find the warning in PyLint's list of messages/codes, so I cannot get it's code to force PyLint to ignore it. How can I find the code?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157982/how-do-i-disable-todo-warnings-in-pylint

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by generating the PyLint config file:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

and then changed this line

```
notes=FIXME,XXX,TODO
```

in it to

```
notes=
```